# Create Dash App in Google Collab with python 3.8

Tags: python-3.x, google-colaboratory, plotly-dash

I had a dash app script in google colab that was preiously working. As of December 2022.  I went to run the script yesterday and I received and error on this part:

```
from jupyter_dash import JupyterDash
```

**ImportError**: cannot import name 'get_current_traceback' from 'werkzeug.debug.tbtools' (/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/werkzeug/debug/tbtools.py)

I cannot share the script as it is from work ba a similar script can be found [here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1_IhLerSP2sC_2pMhj3HpriU7lJatC1Kj?usp=sharing#scrollTo=3Xaqxhy8LUGs) that now produces the same error.

I found a way to fix that error by reverting back to a previos version of werkzeug:

```
!pip uninstall werkzeug
!pip install Werkzeug==2.0.0
```

But now I get the error:

**FileNotFoundError:** [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/Werkzeug-1.0.1.dist-info/METADATA'

How can I fix this error, or if I am going down the wrong path what is the best way to get this code working again.

I also tried reverting to a previous version of Python since it seemed to be working before the switch to Python 3.8. But when I run:

```
# first install python 3.7
!sudo apt-get update -y
!sudo apt-get install python3.7
# change alternatives
!sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.7 1
# select python version
!sudo update-alternatives --config python3
# check python version
!python --version
# install pip for new python 
!sudo apt-get install python3.7-distutils
!wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
!python get-pip.py
# upgrade pip
!sudo apt install python3-pip
!python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

and then run:

```
!python --version
import sys
 
 
print("User Current Version:-", sys.version)
```

I get 3.7 for "!python --version" and 3.8 for "print("User Current Version:-", sys.version)".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the link you gave, I think you can revise something as below to make it work.

- First: Install jupyter dash by `!pip install jupyter-dash -q`
- Second: Change from `app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)` to `app = JupyterDash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)`
- Third: Change from: `if __name__ =='__main__': app.run_server(host="127.0.0.1", port="8030", debug=False)` to `app.run_server(port=8034, mode='inline')`

[image]
Hope this help.

Comment: Thanks Hoa! 

This is exactly what I needed and has saved me a lot of space and time on the !pip installations!